# Using 'small' values in progressBar with 9 patch looks bad

Tags: java, libgdx, progress-bar, nine-patch

I'm using `libGDX` ProgressBar. I create it with the next code:

```
style = new ProgressBar.ProgressBarStyle();
style.background = new SpriteDrawable(backgroundImage);
NinePatch fillImage = new NinePatch(new TextureRegion(img2, 1, 1, img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight()), 25, 26, 30, 30);
style.knobBefore = new NinePatchDrawable(fillImage);
style.knobBefore.setMinWidth(0);
style.knobBefore.setRightWidth(0);
style.knobBefore.setLeftWidth(0);

progress = new ProgressBar(0, 30, 0.1f, false, style);
```

When I set a value to a big number, for example 15 this is how it looks:[1]

but when I set a small value 1/30 (smaller the the basic 9 patch image) it looks bad:

Any ideas how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting your NinePatch width to be less than the minimum. The left and right do not change, so the minimum width your NinePatch can be  is `25 + 26 = 51px`. Any less than this you will get erroneous results. I believe the reason it looks like that is because your sides are actually pushing through each other, creating a negative width for the centre, which is still completely acceptable to draw with. (You can see in your image that the right is at the very far left, the left is most likely at the very far right but behind the reversed middle) The simplest solution would just be to limit the progress bar width to the proper minimum with something like this (if progress value is between 0 and 1);

```
//convert min width to a ratio
float minProgress = style.knobBefore.getMinWidth() / progressBarLength;

float progress = Math.max(progress, minProgress);
```

getMinWidth() would probably tell you it is 51/52px. You also shouldn't force `setMinWidth()`, `setLeftWidht()`, `setRightWidth()`.

Comment: So you mean I should check with each value I want to set, and convert it to a minimum? but then I would have value of 1/100 -->5/100 with the same size - the minimum

Comment: I haven't used the `ProgressBar` myself but I would assume it actually doesn't allow the `NinePatch` to go lower than it's minimum, is that the case if you don't force `setMinWidth()` on it? If it is really an issue that 0-5% will be the same, maybe you can manually customise it a bit. Try setting the knob to be just `TextureRegionDrawable` to begin with, then when `progress` is > `minProgress` as defined above, switch it to the `NinePatchDrawable`